# what does"pull out" mean here?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

But it seems that only the more eccentric or popular artists are viewed as true artists when working with items normally discarded in the trash pile. Why can’t average people be considered artists when ***they pull the same items out*** and mold them into some form of personal art of their own creating? Maybe it’s because we all have our own pre-set ideas of what art is and isn’t, or who artists are or should be.

I am wondering what ***pull out*** means here.

Comment: The items are *pulled out* of the trash = "taken out" of the trash, "extracted from" the trash, but with a little more sense of effort than those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trash can is typically a deep container.  Google "trash can" and switch to images, and you'll see what comes up.

So if you've thrown something out, and will later need to get it, you'll probably have to reach in and literally pull it out.

But *pull out* does have the general meaning of *to extract* or *to retrieve an embedded or stuck object*.